# Linq Search Principle and child collection with OR statement

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

I have a parent entity that has an `ICollection` of a child entity.
I would like to search the parent and child collection using `OR`.
So if the `parentEntity.Name` OR any of the `childrentEntity.PropertyValue` contains the `searchTerm`, then return the parent entity.

I was assuming that the `SelectMany` would flatten out the children and would allow me to easily search through them.
I also tried 'chaining' my query, but that filtered down the result and didn't work well - I need the OR expression.

My query looks like this

```
var result = from v in parentEntity
             where v.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
             || v.ChildCollection.SelectMany(x => 
                         x.PropertyValue.Contains(searchTerm))
             select v;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Any__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___) extension method:

```
var result = from v in parentEntity
             where v.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
             || v.ChildCollection.Any(x => 
                         x.PropertyValue.Contains(searchTerm))
             select v;
```